# Revert to a git commit that hasn't been pushed?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github

My Unity project stopped taking git pushes a week ago. It said that the file size is too large and exceeds 100 mb. But the commits were successfully made. They just weren't pushed. I imported a plugin today which replaced my main scene.

I didn't commit any of the changes. And the commits I did make are technically still on my commits file or whatever. Is it possible to recover my work through this commit which hasn't been pushed?

Comment: What do you want to do with the several too large commits which are on your local branch/machine, but not yet pushed?  Do you need the work from those commits?  Or, are you trying to do something else?

Comment: If you want to revert back to what you've committed locally `git reset --hard` will do it. You do want to have Unity closed when you do that and you probably want to delete the Library directory as well. When you open the project it may take some time to reimport everything as it rebuilds the Library directory.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Will it work even if the commit hasn't been pushed?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want revert to my last commit which I haven't pushed

Comment: ...but is that "last commit" also too large to push?  You might want to include a branch diagram.  Point out which commits cannot be pushed, which can be pushed, and then which of both groups are wanted.

Comment: You can use git without ever pushing anything. The local repository works exactly the same way, all push does is replicate the local changes to the remote repo.